# printing sub-array in numpy as Matlab does

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

How can you print sub-arrays in numpy the same way Matlab does? I have a 3 by 10000 array and I want to view the first 20 columns. In Matlab you can write

```
a=zeros(3,10000);
a(:,1:20)
  Columns 1 through 15

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 16 through 20

 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

However in Numpy

```
import numpy as np
set_printoptions(threshold=nan)
a=np.zeros((3,10000))
print a[:,0:20]
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
    0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

As you can see numpy prints the first row, then the second row, then the third row. I would like it to maintain the column structure and not the row structure

Thank you very much

PS: One solution would be for example

```
print a[:,0:20].T
[[  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]]
```

but, would consume a lot more of space on screen than desired. it would be great if numpy had this option

Comment: If your array has few rows but many columns, and you don't mind seeing it printed a bit screwy, you can print the transverse of the array with `print a.T`.

Comment: Also it seems that you must import numpy twice, once with `from numpy import *`; `set_printoptions` and `nan` are both from the numpy namespace. Are you using pylab mode in IPython by any chance?

Comment: Well, there are two more (janky) solutions: you can either use the `linewidth` option in `set_printoptions` to increase how much horizontal space each row gets (e.g. `np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)` ), or you can try melding CT Zhu's answer with `set_string_function` to return the array as you want.

Comment: I am using iPython notebook, I was doing from numpy import stuff but here I tried to make the code minimal and forgot. :) linewidth option works fine and I want to accept the solution, but the problem is that since I am using iPython notebook the notebook limits the width of the block as well as the output. So even though I am happy with the solutions provided, in the future if I want to display long views of the array I would love if there is an easy way to have numpy breaking the line automatically

Answer (score 1):

Does this give what you want?

```
>>> for item in a[:,0:20].T:
    print '\t'.join(map(str,item.tolist()))
```

Or this?

```
>>> for item in a[:,0:20]:
    print '\t'.join(map(str,item.tolist()))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time in aswering the question, but... it kind of works, I was looking more for a way to specify how I want numpy to print 2-D arrays.